# PHP - display folders and subfolders only at a particular depth

Tags: php, directory

I'm populating a list of directories(the directories are created dynamically)

```
        $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./../data',
            FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);


        $it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir,
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        $it->setMaxDepth(1);


        foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
            if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
                printf("Folder - %s\n", $fileinfo->getFilename());
                $display2 = sprintf('<option id="optionPHP" class="optionPHP" data-icon="glyphicon-time" value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $fileinfo->getFilename(), $fileinfo->getFilename());
                echo $display2;
            }
        }
```

It displays all folders within 'data' folder. The thing is I want to display directories only at depth../data/Vetri/vetriselvi1

[image: folder path]

Essentially I want to populate only folders at that level.. like vetriselvi1, vetriselvi2 ..etc.
How do I do that?

Comment: Change `../data` to `../data/Vetri` in `$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(.....`.

Comment: The sun is starting to go down somewhere @Darren ;-) as per ^ (give it time).

Comment: haha @Fred-ii- just gone 7.30 morn' here ;-)

Comment: @Darren The folder ../data/Vetri is created dynamically.(there are multiple folders like Vetri.. ). So I need a solution to

Answer (score 0):

So I did a round-about thing to achieve what I wanted to:

```
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
                if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
                    if (preg_match("/_/",$fileinfo->getFilename()) ||  preg_match("/--Select Option--/",$fileinfo->getFilename())) {
                    $display2 = sprintf('<option id="optionPHP" class="optionPHP" data-icon="glyphicon-time" value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $fileinfo->getFilename(), $fileinfo->getFilename());
                    echo $display2;
                    }
                }
```

I tried concatenating the dynamically created folder with a character(for instance here "_"), then did a regex match.